# Validate Model data before ajax method call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view on my application I am creating user registration functionality on partial view(not using any form tag) , I am calling Controller's action method using ajax-jquery & passing user details(model) to action method , before calling ajax method i need to validate user detail at client side. how can i do this?

need to validate model before  ajax call(not using any form tag).

```
@model MVC4Demo.Models.Student

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onClientClick() {        

    var obj = { FirstName: "name",  City: "abc" };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AjaxDemo",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');                
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
</script>


<div id="Main">
<label>Student</label>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
</div>

<p>
    <input type="submit" onclick="onClientClick()" value="Create" />
</p>
</div>


<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to put <form> tag around your data? It can be even an empty <form> tag. jquery.validate.unobtrusive requires to have a form around your validating fields.

Comment: @migontech I am implementing registration functionality on partial view & I already have form tag on parent view, at the time of registration i need to validate values of only partial view not whole form

Answer (score 0):

Put your model into form. After:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#myForm').unbind('submit');
    $('#myForm')
        .bind('submit', function () {
            var form = this;
            if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
                $.post('/Home/AjaxDemo', $(form).serialize(), function (data) {

                    if (data.success) {
                        alert('success');
                    } else {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: As i describe in question , I am not using any form tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid a form tag is required. And something else, you can prepend

```
@Html.EnableClientValidation();
@Html.ValidationSummary(true);
```

to the form.